# How to use not css selector with * in stylesheet

Tags: html, css, asp.net, treeview

Here is my problem:

I have External Style Sheet in which I have "*" selector which defines as:

```
*
{
margin: 0em 4.2em 0em 0em;
padding: 0em;
}
```

Now in my aspx page I have a tree view control. Because of the above selector my tree view is not showing properly.

Here is the code

```
 <div id="treeview" style="padding-right:250px; padding-left:150px; width:1040px;margin-left:495px;">
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowLines="true" SelectedNodeStyle-ForeColor="Green" CssClass="TreeViewClass" Style="margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em !important;"
            SelectedNodeStyle-VerticalPadding="0" Target="_blank">


    </asp:TreeView>

</div>
```

So by removing the margin from "*" selector it is working properly but other elements are getting disturbed. So I have added the Style attribute in the TreeView control i.e. inline. But It is not working. I have also tried making a different cssclass for treeview but does not help me.

I have also tried using the not selector of css but that doesn't work for me.

Please I need your help. What should I do to keep these both styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As litelite said; Your first issue lies in the invalid style attributes. Those will likely cause problems on some browsers.

Now, my personal opinion is that you should avoid using an asterisk in your CSS at all. For future projects I would recommend a reset.css or normalize.css instead but since I don't know much about your project, I'll assume that you want a 'quick' fix - You should be able to use the following (this doesn't actually require `:not` )

```
* {
    margin: 0 4.2em 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#treeview * {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah sure from on-wards I will not use * selector. But this time if I remove it I will need to change a lot of pages which I do not want.

Comment: Try my edited solution. I think the `:not(#treeview)` would only remove the margin from the #treeview element and I presume you want to remove the margin from **all** elements inside the #treeview element?

Comment: Great! It worked. Thank you so much. You save me:) You are great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your style attribute is incorrect. The *padding-removed* attribute does not exist and even if it existed it is improperly writen (missing the ':' between the attribute name and the value).

When a style attribute is incorrect browsers usually just discard them.

Comment: Hi. i am sorry it was some editing mistake. I copied my code here so some irrelevant elements showed up. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

*:not(#treeview) should work for you.

```
*:not(#treeview)
{
     margin: 0em 4.2em 0em 0em;
     padding: 0em;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried this code:

```
*:not(asp){
 margin: 0em 4.2em 0em 0em;
 padding: 0em;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned by you I tried the above code but it is not working.